# Scheduled Task .net C# error (0xc000041d)

Tags: c#, .net, scheduled-tasks, com-interop

I wrote a C# console application, running in Task Scheduler, that is working with a 3rd party COM library. The application iterates through thousands of records, each record using this 3rd party library to execute some logic.

I've narrowed down the failure to a new object instantiation from this library, but there are no exceptions; the code just stops even though it's wrapped in a Try\Catch statement. The only error messages that I can find are in Event Viewer -> Application:

**Error 1**
Exception code: 0xc000041d
Fault offset: 0x000ceada

**Error 2**
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000ceada

Unfortunately, the exception doesn't happen on the same record each time and I've also tried running on multiple servers thinking it was environmental but it still errors.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to begin troubleshooting this issue? What do these errors mean?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think windows is terminating the application.  I would run code with task manager open and see what is happening with the memory.  I suspect a memory leak.  I don't think use get Windows Last Error will help, although it is a suggestion.

Comment: Code that dies with this exception is not going to be very happy about having to run in a console mode app.  And even less happy about running as a scheduled task.  You'll have to talk to the library author or vendor about it, but the expected response is "we did not test this kind of usage and cannot support it".  If you don't use any threads yourself then putting the [STAThread] attribute on your Main() method might help work around it.  Albeit that can cause other problems, you don't have a warranty.

Comment: I created a dump of the exception and the Exception Information it's providing says: "The thread tried to read from or write to a virtual address for which it does not have the appropriate access". Does this still sound like a bug in the COM Library or more of how my application is handling creating and dumping objects from that COM Library? What would cause this Access Exception?